# Best way of distributing a pyinstaller exe to the end user (GIT + ADO)

Tags: python, git, azure-devops, pyinstaller

I need some advice on what is the best way to distribute my python application converted to an exe using pyinstaller to end-users. I use GIT repo and the build and release pipeline is via azure devops.
I need an easy way to distribute the exe/readme/ini file as a zip file to the end-user. Ideally, a link that can be sent to the user and they can download the latest zip.
Does anyone have any advice in doing it?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a workaround , after generating the execution file through `pyinstaller`, we can create a .zip archive file by adding [Archive Files task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/archive-files?view=azure-devops).

[image]

Then we can publish this .zip file as a Universal Package to Artifact by using the [Azure CLI](https://learn.microsoft.com/cli/azure/?view=azure-cli-latest).

**Publish a Universal Package:**

```
az artifacts universal publish --organization https://dev.azure.com/xxx --feed xxx --name my-first-package --version 1.0.0 --description "Your description" --path .
```

Then users can download the Universal Package by providing the name and version. For example:

```
az artifacts universal download --organization https://dev.azure.com/xxx --feed xxx --name my-first-package --version 1.0.0 --path .
```

**Note**: You must use the Azure CLI to download the package. Azure DevOps doesn't support direct HTTP/HTTPS download links or other ways to download the package.

For details ,please refer to this official [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/artifacts/quickstarts/universal-packages?view=azure-devops&tabs=azuredevops).